# By default which HTML form input will get focus when I input with enter key

Tags: html

By default which HTML form input will get focus when I input with enter key?

Is this related with the input order in the html source?

I don't know the hidden rules of it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the next one declared in order.  If you had the following...  The input `last-name` would get the focus after `first-name`.

```
<input type="text" name="first-name" />
<input type="text" name="last-name" />
<input type="text" name="city" />
```